# simulate Web Page keystroke

Tags: c#

Is it possible for C# app to simulate keystrokes on a web Page?
for example, there is jsp page and I need input text data and click the submit button on that page.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different options:

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org)
- [WaitN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

are open source projects that provide functional web testing.  You can use testing frameworks like NUnit, xUnit, mbUnit to playback your tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). Selenium is, basically, a unit test framework for web sites, and the Remote Control part is simply an API you can use in C# (among other languages).

Comment: You may want to check out http://seleniumtoolkit.codeplex.com/ that provides C# utilities for Selenium RC

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [webbrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28VS.85%29.aspx) to load the page ... Input data and press the subit button (or any button).

Here is a sample VB.net code which inputs username and password and clicks the "login" button.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.foo.com/login.php")

While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
   Application.DoEvents()
End While

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_login").SetAttribute("Value", "username")
                    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("Value","password")
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("loginform").InvokeMember("submit")
```

I know you are looking for a c# code. Give me 5 mins and I will post.

Edit: Here is the c# code

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.foo.com/login.php");

     while (WebBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
         Application.DoEvents();
     }

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_login").SetAttribute("Value", "username");
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_pass").SetAttribute("Value", "password");
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("loginform").InvokeMember("submit");
```

Note: I dont have VS now. So let me know if this code does not work

Answer (score 0):

if you can read Italian, take a look at this post:
http://www.innovactive.it/post/2009/09/04/Test-della-UI-di-una-applicazione-con-Selenium.aspx
it's about testing an app UI with Selenium.