# How do I click an ASP.NET webform's button when the page is hosted in a WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a standard ASP.NET web form in a web page, and this page is hosted in a .NET Winform with a WebBrowser Control. Using c# how do I control the WebBrowser Control to submit the ASP.NET form? (eg somehow "clicking" on the button from the Winform?)

**Update**: to complicate things we have the ASP.NET validators which seem to make simple document.forms(0).submit() not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the complication of the ASP.NET validators somehow messing with the normal form.submit() flow the submit button's click method had to be called:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("mybutton").InvokeMember("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question. Check this : [simulate Web Page keystroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477846/simulate-web-page-keystroke/1477971#1477971)

You can use the following code

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("loginform").InvokeMember("submit");
```

Comment: Thanks, almost worked, but the ASP.NET validators stop you from directly calling form.submit()

Comment: May be you missed to fill in any form fields?

Comment: I think that the validators actually stop the form.submit event from firing as you get no message saying fields aren't filled out like you would when you press the button normally.