# Connecting "Directly" to a website DataBase or Screen Scraping

Tags: asp.net, web, screen-scraping

The following link (https://www.misim.gov.il/svinfonadlan2010/) is a form which after filling and submitting, retrieves information about housing dealing throughout Israel (it's in Hebrew).
I need to somehow programmatically fetch the data (without filling the forum manually).

What are my options ??
(Note that the forum contains CAPTCHA).

P.S : I found an Israeli website which does exactly that (http://www.hamapa.co.il/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of options.  Check out the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041(v=vs.85).aspx) Control in ASP.NET.

Navigate to the page and you can auto populate the controls of the page by iterating the controls.

An example of this is:  [Manipulate/Change/Form Fill data in webpages using the Webbrowser control](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?416275-Manipulate-Change-Form-Fill-data-in-webpages-using-the-Webbrowser-control/page2)

You can then [Auto click the Submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508091/how-do-i-click-an-asp-net-webforms-button-when-the-page-is-hosted-in-a-webbrows)

The biggest obstacle you have to overcome is the Captcha which I have little knowledge of working with other than screen scraping it.